# CORS authentication in Internet Explorer using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cors, basic-authentication

I've got a number of questions I *could* ask but I'll start with this one for now as it's bugging me the most.

I have a development environment (intranet zone) and a web service (internet zone) that requires authentication so I'm using CORS. After a lot of research the server's been setup to correctly respond to CORS requests; of this I'm 100% certain.

The web service has been setup to allow basic as well as cookie based authentication. For my development environment I've decided to opt for basic as it's nice and simple and works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. That is, when the web service is called using the following JQuery Ajax, the browser presents a popup and allows me to log in.

```
$.ajax({type:'GET',
    url:'https://whatever.com/theservice',
    xhrFields: {'withCredentials': true},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
         //do something
    }
});
```

The response from the server (abbreviate and for info):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mysandbox/
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
```

However, IE10 does not allow this (does not show the credentials popup) but at least there's a security option that will enable this behaviour: Setting the "Access data sources across domains" option to "Enable" and hey presto, it works like a dream and I start getting the popup. This is acceptable because it's only a development environment and not destined for release in this format.

However, when I come to test this same example in IE8/9 (which is necessary unfortunately) with the same security option set, the browser receives the 401 response but does not show the popup. For info, I'm using the [jQuery.XDomainRequest.js](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest/blob/master/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js) library to add CORS capability for IE8/9.

So my question: Am I missing something or does IE8/9 simply not support the basic credentials popup during an Ajax call?

Comment: IE8/9's XDomainRequest is [extremely limited](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).

Comment: But if I pre-authenticate in my browser session on the server hosting the web service, the Authorization header will actually sent by the browser during the Ajax calls. Edit: Sorry no it won't, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the XDomainRequest object used in IE8/IE9 has several serious limitations, including the fact that you can't add custom headers to your requests.

Here is a comprehensive list of limitations you should be aware of :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

The main workarounds I know about (and you could look into) when it comes to Cross Domain requests are :

- JSONP
- Using Flash or Silverlight
- Hosting an API for the distant service on your own domain

Comment: So in actual fact, it is impossible to use CORS in IE8/9 if the web service requires authentication?

Comment: Given my experience, I cannot give a definitive answer. However, my feeling is you can't do this using CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I just realised that I didn't need to use the CORS XDomainRequest in IE8/9 when the "Access data sources across domains" security option is set to "Enable". The reason I didn't realise this sooner is because, my web page was on HTTP and the service is on HTTPS. After switching my page to HTTPS and removing the jQuery.XDomainRequest.js plugin, it all started working like a charm and I got the Basic Authentication popup when accessing the service during the Ajax call. IE7 did not work though but that's no big deal.